# Excel to PowerPoint Export without formatting Excel Worksheet via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have managed to create a VBA Macro that exports various charts and tables to PPT, however, at the moment I am encountering the following issue:

When a chart is exported to PPT, the format that is defined in the VBA code is applied also in the Excel Worksheet (dimensions, legend, title). Can someone provide me with possible tips in a way that the above-mentioned options will be applied only within PPT but remain unchanged in Excel?

This is the code that I have tried so far:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Width = 380
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Height = 125
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Border.LineStyle = xlNone
'ActiveChart.HasTitle = False
'ActiveChart.HasLegend = False   
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
With cht
    .HasLegend = False
    .HasTitle = False
End With
Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
    newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 90
    newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 138
```

I am pretty sure that there is an alternative method that does this, but I am not aware of it yet.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of the settings and revert when done.

```
acW = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Width
acH = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Height
acBLS = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).).Border.LineStyle

' your code

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Width = acW
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Height = acH
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Border.LineStyle = acBLS
```